# Package listed in MELPA, but not found in package install

Tags: emacs, ensime, melpa

I am currently trying to install ENSIME for emacs 24.3.1 following the instructions at https://github.com/ensime/ensime-emacs under the quick start; I've added

```
    (require 'package)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
    (package-initialize)

(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

to my .emacs file, as instructed.  However, when I restart and do M-x package install [RETURN]ensime[RETURN], it returns [No Match] and indeed, I can't find it when I list the packages.  However, I can easily find it at http://melpa.milkbox.net/#; what would be causing the discrepancy between what is available through the website and when can be installed from emacs?

Any help is much appreciated; Thank you!

Comment: I've experienced this same problem, and looking at my Emacs config the only difference is that I have `'("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))` - note the missing `t` argument at the end. Can't remember if this fixed the problem for me or not, but it's easy enough to try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm afraid it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try an explicit `M-x packaged refresher contents` before `package-install`?

Comment: With `M-: package-archives` you can see the contents of the variable `package-archives`.  You might find that it is not what you thought you set it to.  In my case as some point I had it customized in custom-set-variables (auto saved at end of .emacs) and this overrides the value I set earlier.

Comment: the 't' at the end of the add-to-list call is just so it appends it.

Comment: @lunaryorn it was `M-x package-refresher-contents` - it really helped! Thanks!

Comment: After fixing @lunaryorn's typos: `M-x package-refresh-contents`, this worked for me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In my .emacs file I have

```
;; packages
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
  )
```

Then, `M-x package-list-packages`

`C-s ensime`

and there you go:

**ensime             20140718.... available  ENhanced Scala Interaction Mode for Emacs**

Are you sure your emacs can actually get access to internet?

Comment: it's worth pointing out that this is now outdated, please use http://ensime.org/editors/emacs/install

Comment: That's great, thanks! The question is why `package-install` did not find it (I had the same problem with `clang-format`).

Comment: @Gauthier I found the same behavior. Turns out the package I wanted was already installed that is why `package-install` could not detect it.

Comment: Thanks @MiniFridge that was the problem for me. :)

Answer (score 124):

I had to run M-x package-refresh-contents. Once I did that, the files were found.

Here's what my .emacs looks like:

```
(cond
 ((>= 24 emacs-major-version)
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
           '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (package-refresh-contents)
 )
)
```

Comment: But [getting started](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) on Melpa says `Enable installation of packages from MELPA by adding an entry to package-archives after (require 'package) and before the call to package-initialize in your init.el or .emacs file: `

Comment: That reversed order likely is what is causing the need for refreshing; ultimately they're the same thing at startup because the package-initialize has nothing to initialize until after add-to-list. I haven't tried this but I will.

Comment: calling `package-refresh-contents` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Isn't `((>= 24 emacs-major-version)` the wrong way 'round?

Answer (score 14):

After doing the usual editing of .emacs to make melpa avalaible and restarting Emacs, I searched the list of packages for the one I wanted.

```
M-x package-list-packages
C-s <package_name>
```

Then I clicked on the name of the package and pressed the install button.  I am unsure as to why `M-x package-install RET <package_name>` failed, but clicking the install button worked for me.

Comment: Same issue when trying to install `magit` when running `M-x package-install RET magit` which kept indicating no matches. It showed related packages such as `magit-svn`, `magit-p4`, etc. but not simply `magit`.  However, your suggested answer worked in installing it.

Comment: @RayVega I'm glad to know my answer is helping others; thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 4):

*Emacs v28.2*

In my case it seems that a previous attempt at getting started with Emacs left me with a "stale" config file `~/.emacs` which somehow clashed with `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

So I just deleted `~/.emacs` and things started making sense again.

Make sure you have this in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

Then:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-refresh-content` <kbd>⏎</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>⏎</kbd>
- `<your-package-name>` <kbd>⏎</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! I followed the directions in your post and I got my new package of interested installed.